# Error Formating Volume – Can’t format 1 TB Toshiba external

Tags: external-hard-drive, linux-mint, formatting

A neighbor brought me a disk to see if I can do something about it. 
Windows doesn't detect it.
Trying Linux, I get the following:

[image: Toshiba disk information - Linux Disk utility]

And when I try formatting, I get this:

```
Error wiping device: Command-line `wipefs -a "/dev/sdd"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: wipefs: error: /dev/sdd: probing initialization failed: Device or resource busy
 (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

Does it have a solution or should I throw it?

Comment: Device or resource busy would tend to indicate the drive is in use. Have you tried deleting all the volumes / partitions then recreating a single volume and formatting?

Comment: any recommendations on how to properly do that?
the only option i seem to have is 'format partition' and it doesn't work